# Adding dynamic DisplayObjects in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

I am adding DisplayObjects to a Canvas using

```
ContentContainer.addChild(c);
```

Where ContentContainer is my Canvas object and c is the DisplayObject I have created at run-time

Some of these DisplayObjects also have children of there own which are added at run-time prior to the DisplayObject being added to the Canvas

I then need to iterate over all the children of ContentContainer but the first time I do this, it says that ContentContainer has no children (ie, ContentContainer.numChildren = 0).  If I do it again tho then it is fine and returns the correct number of children.

Is there something I need to call to get ContentContainer to recalculate how many children it has?

Comment: Can you post the code showing where numChildren == 0?  Is it called from the same method that does addChild() or on some other path?

Comment: I am seeing that numChildren==0 in both the debugger in Flex Builder and (the bit that is screwing me over) when I do

for (var i:uint=0; i<ContentContainer.numChildren; i++)
{
...
}

The code is in 2 different methods.  Also the items are being added but the next stage (where it iterates through them) doesn't happen until the user clicks a button

Comment: Can you post your full code? Are the adding of children and the iterating over the children handled in separate functions? Maybe they're being called in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael noted it would be helpful to see the code but you might want to look into the **Event overview** and **About the creation policy** sections in the docs - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_3.html

Specifically the childAdd event might be what you want to listen for before you iterate over it:

> `add` Dispatched by a component after the component has been added to its container and the parent and the child are in a consistent state. This event is dispatched after the container has dispatched the `childAdd` event and all changes that need to be made as result of the addition have happened.

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  Unfortunately I don't think this is the issue because I can see that the children have been created ok before I click the button that iterates through them - ie the DisplayObjects themselves are visible on the screen.

Also, as the iteration doesn't happen until I click a button, I can wait for any length of time after the DisplayObjects are added before I start the iteration but even if I give it a few minutes from when I can see the DisplayObjects on the screen, I still get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar task with a callLater in order to wait till after a dragdrop completed before recalculating some tasks. This might work for you.

```
public function myFunct():void{
    //do your adding
    callLater(
        function():void{
            //do your loop
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  Unfortunately I don't think timing is the issue here because once the items are added, the iteration through them doesn't happen until the user clicks a button.  No matter how I long I wait between loading the items and clicking the button, I still get the same problem